# Gradle + TestNG only runs certain tests as single tests

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, gradle, testng

I've been using Gradle + TestNG + Java + Selenium for my web UI tests for quite a while now and I've only recently run in to this issue. For some reason when I try to run a single test class using `-DtaskName.single=ExampleTestClass` where `ExampleTestClass` would be `ExampleTestClass.java` it only works on some of my test classes.

I'm getting the error: `Could not find a matching test for pattern: ExampleTestClass`

I've seen this error in the past due to typos or missing `@Test` annotations etc, so I'm familiar with the "normal" cause, but this is quite bizarre as it appears to work on some test classes and not others. I've inspected the code and all annotations and groups are in place for the test methods, they run fine from my IDE (IntelliJ), and they are all located in the same directory / package path. Is there something I'm missing here? I don't know if I'm seeing things but I did notice that it didn't work with a test class that did not have `Test` as the last four characters of the Java class name but upon renaming it, still no dice. I've read the documentation and can't find anything wrong. Is there anything else that may be causing this to fail? It's quite odd since these tests are all so similar in every way. I even checked character encoding etc - no discrepancies between any of them.

Any advice or ideas on where to look next would be great.

Cheers,
Darwin

Comment: If you can't explain it and don't find anything in the debug log (`--debug`), the best chance is to debug the Gradle build and see what's going on. You could also try the new `--tests` (see [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for details, haven't checked if it's already supported for TestNG), which is set to replace `-DtestTaskName.single`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Yeah I did try the new `--tests` flag as well which I found (a bit to my surprise) in the Gradle docs and got the same error (I believe the error wording was slightly different but it was the same problem). The odd thing is that some tests run fine and some are not found, all in the same folder. Anything I should be looking for in the debug log? I did go over it but it's pretty verbose and I couldn't see anything new that appeared to relate to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same thing with gradle 1.6 (haven't had time to upgrade), and TestNG. A single test in a project with multiple tests get skipped and also gradle complains about not finding it if you try running the single test alone. Debug run shows the missing test .class file being found by gradle.

I worked around it by adding an @Test annotation to the test *class* in addition to the test method. That seems to make gradle find it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar issue.  I tried to run a test with `-DTest.single` and `--tests` but it wasn't found.  After a bit of frustration I realized that the test was in a test group that was excluded in my test task configuration.  I had incorrectly assumed that running with `-Dtest.single` would overrule exclusions, including that test's group allowed it to run as a single test.